# Exception trying read an excel file by OleDb?

Tags: c#

I'm trying read an excel file using `OleDb` but an exception is always throw. How could I do this ?

trying

```
private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            try {
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + 
                                                            FILE_PATH + ";Extended Properties=\\Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"");
                String sql = "select * from [alunos.unid2.xls$]";
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);

                conn.Open();
                OleDbDataReader rs = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (rs.NextResult()) {
                    //Console.WriteLine(rs["ALU_NOME"]);
                    strBuilder.Append(rs["ALU_NOME"]);
                }
                conn.Close();
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

**Exception**

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 130.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FILE_PATH + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;'");
```

You are missing opening quote for value of `Extended Properties`